# Why do "page-break-inside:avoid' added element overlapping with other element after page break in PDF?

Tags: html, css, wkhtmltopdf

I'm using 'page-break-inside:avoid' to break div to next page in PDF and its perfectly working but overlapping with other element when page break

[HTML image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vs43o.jpg)

[PDF image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z3k23.jpg)

i am using 'wkhtmltopdf' to convert html to PDF

```
<div style="page-break-inside:avoid;>
  Portable Document Format (PDF) is a file format used to present and exchange 
   documents reliably
</div>
```

This is the div which is overlapping with other in PDF

I expect it will not overlap with other element when page break, but its overlapping

Comment: Did you find the solution for this, I have the exact issue.